# Get Response and HTML data from String in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm getting some data from API in this format

```
"Optional(SBKK.PolicyEntity(errorCode: Optional("222"), message: nil, httpBody: Optional("<html>\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\">\n<style>\n  .title {\n    color: blue;\n  }\n\n  .desc {\n    color: #333;\n    font-size: 12px;\n  }\n</style>\n\n<body>\n  <h1 class=\"title\">CONST</h1>\n  <p class=\"desc\">TEST</p>\n</body>\n\n</html>")))"
```

which is `String` type in this moment.
I have a `Policy Entity` like this

```swift
struct PolicyEntity: BaseResponse, Decodable {
    var errorCode: String?
    var message: String?
    var httpBody: String?
}
```

And Im getting a data from API with this code

```swift
func sendGetStringRequest<T:BaseResponse>(_ router: RouterProtocol,
                                              _ type: T.Type,
                                              successHandler: @escaping(T)-> (),
                                              failHandler: @escaping(ErrorCode?)-> ()) {
        
        guard let request = try? router.asURLRequest() else {
            failHandler(ErrorCode())
            return
        }
        
        print("AF.request starts")
        AF.request(request).responseString { (response: AFDataResponse<String>) in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                guard let model = try? PolicyEntity.init(httpBody: response.value) else {
                    print("AF.request failure")
                    failHandler(ErrorCode())
                    return
                }
                successHandler(model as! T)
            
            case .failure (let error):
                print("AF.request string error: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
```

I would like to display the data from response (from httpBody) in my WebView. But I'm not able to parse this without some string indexing and cutting. Is there a better way to parse this data to the entity?

Comment: Could you print `String(data: response.value, encoding: .utf8)`?

Comment: Cannot convert value of type 'String?' to expected argument type 'Data'

Comment: try `print(response.value)` just after `case .success:`

Comment: Optional("<html>\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\">\n<style>\n  .title {\n    color: blue;\n  }\n\n  .desc {\n    color: #333;\n    font-size: 12px;\n  }\n</style>\n\n<body>\n  <h1 class=\"title\">DESC</h1>\n  <p class=\"desc\">TEST</p>\n</body>\n\n</html>")

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that it was a `AFDataResponse<String>`. You have raw HTML, so get that value and load it into your webview?